# SendMessage in to FCM gives time out

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have below code.  Initialisation is succeeded.  But when I try to send an message it is timing out.

I am trying to send message from kubernetes pod to FCM.  I verified the internet access and it is there.  i tried this url to check the internet connection.

```
curl -I "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
```

I get "Connection established" message

Exception thrown :

> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Timed out while making an API call: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out, iss: firebase-adminsdk-xxxxx@xxxx-xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com

I have followed the steps exactly in firebase app server settings page.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ClassPathResource(firebaseConfigPath).getInputStream())).build();
        if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }

   Message message = Message.builder()
                    .putData("score", "850")
                    .putData("time", "2:45")
                    .setToken(request.getToken())
                    .build();
             response1 = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

Can anyone give me pointers?